# how to add iCal4j dependencies in addition to the iCal4j library in android?

Tags: android, file, dependencies, icalendar

I am trying to parse the ical file with ical4j, i have added ical4j jar file to project but have problem in adding  iCal4j dependencies in addition to the iCal4j library. As specified in

`http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=FAQ`

Any idea how can I do this?

In addition to this, can anyone provide with ical file parse example ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to add the ical4j dependencies along with ical4j.

But still looking for some sample parse examples